# #include <mmdeviceapi.h> unresolved inclusion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, volume

I am trying to make a command line application to get the system volume.
I copied the code from here: https://gist.github.com/rdp/8363580
However, it won't build.
The line that says "#include ", there is an error saying "Unresolved inclusion: ".

I am using MinGW and Eclipse.

Comment: I have a file `mmdeviceapi.h` in my mingw `include` directory. Can you check if that file exists in yours? Maybe you have an old mingw release?

Comment: @rodrigo Nope, no idea why. I just got mingw two days ago...

Comment: There are a few old mingw releases out there, maybe you have one of them. I recommend [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) (not just for 64-bits).

Comment: Well, I ran the executable... Not sure what to do now that I have two mingw installations...

Comment: Probably in Eclipse there are some options to select the compiler to be used. Or maybe you just configure the system `PATH`?

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much!